# geometry question triangles

Tags: geometry

Let $ABC$ be a triangle in which $CA = BA$  and $∠CAB = 90^\circ$. Suppose $M$ and $N$ are points on $BC$ such that $CN:NM:MB=3:5:4$. How do I prove that angle $MAN=45$.

Answer (score 1):

Without loss of generality (using coordinate geometry) let $A=(0,0)$, $B=(12,0)$ and $C=(0,12)$. Then $N=(3,9)$ and $M=(8,4)$. Applying the dot product we see:

$$AN\cdot AM=3\times8+9\times4=\sqrt{3^2+9^2}\sqrt{8^2+4^2}\cos A$$

$$60=\sqrt{7200}\cos A$$

$$60=60\sqrt{2}\cos A$$

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}=\cos A$$

$$A=45.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let's work in the $(A, \overrightarrow{AB}, \overrightarrow{AC})$ orthogonal coordinate system.
In this system, we have $M(\frac{8}{12},\frac{4}{12})$ and $N(\frac{3}{12}, \frac{9}{12})$.

Let's proceed by calculating :
$AM = \sqrt{(\frac{8}{12})^2 + (\frac{4}{12})^2} = \frac{\sqrt{80}}{12}$,
$AN = \sqrt{(\frac{3}{12})^2 + (\frac{9}{12})^2} = \frac{\sqrt{90}}{12}$,
$MN = \sqrt{(\frac{8}{12}-\frac{3}{12})^2 + (\frac{4}{12}-\frac{9}{12})^2} = \frac{\sqrt{50}}{12}$.

We now use the law of cosines :
$MN^2 = AM^2 + AN^2 - 2 \cdot AM \cdot AN \cdot \cos(\widehat{MAN})$

This gives us :
$\cos(\widehat{MAN}) = \frac{AM^2 + AN^2 - MN^2}{2 \cdot AM \cdot AN} = \frac{80 + 90 - 50}{2 \sqrt{7200}} = \frac{120}{120 \sqrt{2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

We can conclude that $\widehat{MAN} = 45°$

Answer (score 0):

[image]

**Construction:**

- triangle $AC'B$ congruent to $ABC$ having common base $AB$.
- Place points $M'$ and $N'$ on $BC'$ such that $BN'=CN$ and $AM=AM'$

**Observations:**

- $NAN'=90$ and $MAM'=90$
- $MBN'=90$.
- And you have $MN'=MN$
- Triangles $NAM$ and $MAN'$ are congreunt.

Implying $N'AM=MAN=45$

Comment: Why is $NAN'$ and $MAM'$ 90 degree? You haven't used the 3:5:4 ratio which is required for this problem to work.

Comment: I have used to prove that MN' =MN=5*(something)!  (note MBN'=90)